# Mostrar registros SqlLite en Android sin Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, sqlite

Quisiera saber si alguien me podría ayudar con la siguiente duda.
Existe alguna manera de ver los registros de una base de datos creada en SQLite sin el `Android Device Monitor` el problema que en la nueva versión de `android 3.1` ya no existe esa herramienta. Si alguien me podría ayudar se los agradecería. O si se puede mostrarla en el mismo dispositivo o emulador.

Comment: Instalé AS 3.1 y es verdad no aparece el icono o la opción del menú para iniciar el ADM @Chama se debe realizar por linea de comandos de acuerdo a la documentación.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo hago es lo siguiente amigo. 
Primero, descargo el sqliteBroswer el cual es un programa que nos ayudara muchisimo con esto

http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Posteriormente lo que haremos es sacar una copia de la base de datos que tengas en tu aplicacion. Para esto usaremos la consola de comandos y ADB (Android device Bridge). Debes asingnar la ruta del ADB a una variable de entorno de tu sistema para usarlo sin ningun problema.

Y ya, con eso solo te queda usar el siguiente comando.

```
adb pull /data/data/com.example.app.development/databases/App.db
```

Donde la ruta haria referencia a la ruta donde esta instalada tu app.

De esta manera haremos una copia de tu base de datos en cualquier momento y la abriremos con el programa que mencione al principio y asi podremos ver toda la informacion que esta en la base de datos de tu app en cualquier momento.

Espero esto haya sido de ayuda, cualquier cosa estare pendiente en los comentarios.

Answer (score -1):

En **Android Studio 3.1** la única forma de entrar al [ADM](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html), se realiza mediante linea de comandos.

> [**Device Monitor disponible desde la línea de comandos.** En Android Studio 3.1, Device Monitor cumple una función menor a la que
>   desempeñaba anteriormente. En muchos casos, la funcionalidad
>   disponible a través del Monitor de Dispositivo ahora es provista por
>   herramientas nuevas y mejoradas.](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html#device_monitor_available_from_the_command_line)

Debes entrar mediante linea de comandos al directorio de tu SDK, después al directorio `/tools` y ahí ejecutas `monitor`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es importante comentar que `Android Studio` debe estar cerrado ya que este usa un puerto necesario para el `Android Device Monitor`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.